# What could be the cause of unexpected characters served by the PHP internal web server?

Tags: php, html, docker, utf-8, php-7

I am running the PHP internal web server inside a Docker container based on Alpine 3.8.

This serves a simple page, which is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            This is a 'hello world' for my CD container.
        </div>
        <p>
            Version: <?php echo getenv('CD_DEMO_VERSION') ?>
        </p>
        <p>
            GUID: <?php echo file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/guid.txt') ?>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have this in a CircleCI build process, and a PHPUnit reads the HTML using `simplexml_load_string()` in order to check it is working. Most of the time it is fine, but occasionally it is adding control-character cruft either to the start or the end of the HTML, causing the HTML parsing to fail. I would say this happens 10% of the time, so it is hard to replicate. It does not seem to happen locally.

In this build process I am waiting for the web server to start up, so I don't think there is a race-condition happening here.

If the cruft occurs at the start, it looks like this (my output swaps carriage returns to the `⏎` symbol, this is not seen by the XML processor):

```
^@^@<html>⏎    <head>⏎        <title>Test page</title>⏎    </head>⏎    <body>⏎        <div>⏎            This is a 'hello world' for my CD container.⏎        </div>⏎        <p>⏎            Version:         </p>⏎        <p>⏎            GUID: 47294362a6154e9a5397a9f9b72cefe1d349ec2e31de12e6084746a084e4e4ef        </p>⏎    </body>⏎</html>
```

If the cruft appears at the end, it looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>⏎<html>⏎    <head>⏎        <title>Test page</title>⏎    </head>⏎    <body>⏎        <div>⏎            This is a 'hello world' for my CD container.⏎        </div>⏎        <p>⏎            Version:         </p>⏎        <p>⏎            GUID: a721f44d05e93debb593eef135fc664fb6b0d3aa6a04d50af7f17339d0d75399        </p>⏎    </body>⏎</html>⏎^@^@
```

I don't know if these are actual circumflexes and at symbols, or whether this is just how the random stuff is rendered to my screen.

It looks like the web server is serving a UTF-8 character set header.

I think my PHPUnit test is relevant, so I will add it here. Due to a way in which CircleCI works, I cannot publish a Docker port on the outside of a container, so I am using `docker exec` to do an HTTP operation from the inside:

```
public function testApp()
{
    // Get the page and convert it to an XML object
    $html = $this->getWebPage();

    // CI is giving me some parsing issues, so let's see it
    echo str_replace("\n", "⏎", $html);

    $doc = simplexml_load_string($html);
    $message = trim((string) $doc->body->div);

    $this->assertEquals(
        "This is a 'hello world' for my CD container.",
        $message
    );
}

protected function getWebPage()
{
    $output = $return = null;
    $command = sprintf(
        'docker exec -ti %s php -r "echo file_get_contents(\'http://localhost\');"',
        escapeshellarg($this->getRepoName())
    );
    exec($command, $output, $return);

    // Check return value first
    if ($return)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(
            sprintf(
                'Returned a failure exit code %d on Docker operation',
                $return
            )
        );
    }

    $imploded = implode(PHP_EOL, $output);

    return $imploded;
}
```

### Update

I have updated to Apache 2.4.x inside Alpine 3.8, and to my great surprise, I get exactly the same problem. So, it turns out not to be the PHP web server.

I have also tried Alpine 3.7, same result again. I tried Ubuntu 18.10, same again.

I have tried `php -r` with `file_get_contents()` and `wget` as HTTP devices inside the container.

I am now minded to think that capturing stdout from `docker exec` is at fault. I assume that if I set up my tests in another image and run the containers with Docker Compose, it will probably work. Or, I could use `docker exec`, write to a container file, and then fish the file out with `docker cp`.

It'd still be fascinating to know what is going wrong, though.

Comment: At the start, it is probably an unnecessary utf-8 byte order marker introduced by your editor or your lightweight container. Your served content should be UTF-8 without a BOM.

Comment: I wondered about that, thanks @Dragonthoughts. But it'd be surprising if that were the reason for the same cruft sequence being added to the end though, right? (That case seems to happen less frequently, but it has happened at least once).

Comment: I agree with you. It wouldn't happen at the end. Another possibility could be a buffering issue and you are reading extra, or unused bytes in a buffer.

Comment: I have temporarily switched to using Apache - the total image size is only 24M, which is better than I thought it would be. I'll try hammering that to see if I can get that to fail; if I can't, that'd strengthen the case for it being a PHP web server problem, I think.

Comment: I've updated again @Dragonthoughts - Apache has the same problem. I will try going back to Alpine 3.7, in case there is a problem with this most recent Alpine version. I could use the Ubuntu image too, but my slimline container preference will go right out of the window. `:=)`

Comment: @Dragonthoughts: I have now tried so many things, I suspect a problem with Docker (see my new update). My new guess is that `docker exec` is at fault, so I will work on that angle next.

Comment: It is an interesting problem. I'm sorry I wasn't able to guide you to a solution.
If you telnet to a similar listener, does it appear to read the same bytes as you send?

Comment: No worries @Dragonthoughts, it is still useful to have rubber duck conversations, for which I am appreciative! I think I might have [fixed it with this](https://github.com/halfer/cd-demo-container/commit/0623e4da785e654a39f973e24658f598e3d44eae): instead of using `wget` inside the container and letting it output the result to stdout, I am writing that to a file and then using Docker's copy command. I just got a CI pass from that, so maybe that will fix it.

Comment: If that fails, I will do something with Docker Compose to run the tests in another container (which will bypass CircleCI's port restriction, and thus I won't have to copy from the container to the host).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I surmised in the question, this was fixed by doing a `docker exec` and redirecting the stdout to a temporary file in the container. I then used `docker cp` to fish the file out of the container back to the host.

I didn't find out what caused the strange text artefacts, and wonder if it could be specific to CircleCI.